# using list variable in array set

Tags: tcl

I am learning TCL and found that I can initialize array as (k1,v1 is set of key values)

```
array set a2 {k1 v1 k2 v2}
```

however, when I try to use already existing list as

```
set var3 "k1 v1 k2 v2"
array set a2{$var3}
```

or

```
set var3 [listk1 v1 k2 v2]
array set a2{$var3}
```

I get an error:

> wrong # args: should be 'array set arrayName list"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a space between the array name and the value. The syntax is "array set name value" but you were calling it like "array set namevalue"

```
array set a2 $var3
```

In the other example you included brackets around the variable, which would prevent the variable from being expanded. `${var3}` will expand the same as `$var3`, but `{$var3}` will not.

Comment: Also, no braces around the `$var3`: if you add the space, the braces prevent variable substitution and you get the string "$var3" instead.

Comment: Thanks. removing brackets was the key as even after removing the space,I was getting an error

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when a command invocation goes wrong it helps to look at the command as a list. In this way, one can see approximately how the command will look when it is ready to be executed.

```
list array set a2{$var3}
# -> array set {a2{k1 v1 k2 v2}}
```

Hmm, no, that doesn't look right. There's supposed to be four words, and that third word looks weird.

How about if I put a space before the left brace?

```
list array set a2 {$var3}
# -> array set a2 {$var3}
```

Close, but no cigar. It looks like the braces are interfering with the variable substitution. What if I remove them?

```
list array set a2 $var3
# -> array set a2 {k1 v1 k2 v2}
```

And there was much rejoicing.

In this manner, one can experiment with the command structure and the quoting until one gets it right. Just a tip.

Comment: such a useful tip...Thanks